# Why My Node Package Manager is giving me error after installing it and after running the pacakage.JSON file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

i am learning node.js. I initialized a package.json file in my project and I used a special lifecycle script "start" in my JSON file. Before initializing npm I ran "node app.js" command in terminal to run the code inside app.js. But when I ran the code using NPM, I am getting an error after running this command:

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2021-02-01T15_18_14_323Z-debug.log
```

here are the contents of the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v14.7.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v14.7.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.7
3 info using node@v14.7.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle guide@1.0.0~prestart: guide@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle guide@1.0.0~start: guide@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle guide@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle guide@1.0.0~start: PATH: /Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v14.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/apple/Desktop/guide/node_modules/.bin:/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v14.7.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
9 verbose lifecycle guide@1.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/apple/Desktop/guide
10 silly lifecycle guide@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node app.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle guide@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle guide@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: guide@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v14.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v14.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid guide@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/apple/Desktop/guide
16 verbose Darwin 17.7.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v14.7.0/bin/node" "/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v14.7.0/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v14.7.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.7
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error guide@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the guide@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of the log file in your question? It's at `/Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2021-02-01T15_18_14_323Z-debug.log`, according to the error

Comment: yes i can do that

Answer (score 0):

You should write start like this : `"start" : "node app.js"`. And you must install node_modules. For that you can write console `npm i`. Modules will install and it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to do for creating a start script:

1. First things first, to initialize a node and npm project, there has to be a package.json file. It can be created manually, but it is advisable to use the command `npm init` in the terminal. This command walks you through creating a package.json file asking some questions. You can simply press enter, enter, if you want, but you could also answer them, no problem. You can also skip everything by running `npm init -y` instead of `npm init`.
2. Second, you have to create a script using the **`scripts`** object only, **not anywhere else**. To do that, open the file in your editor, look at where the object resides, or create a new object:

```
{
  "name": "your-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js" // here
  }
}
```

3. Finally, run the script using the command `npm run start` in the terminal.